# Instantiate JavaScript constructor function only if parameter types check

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following constructor function

```
function Planet(solarSystem,habitable) {

    this.solarSystem = solarSystem;
    this.habitable = habitable;

}
```

And I want to create an instance of this constructor function but I put the wrong parameters type (e.g. because I had 4 beers and I felt like programming):

```
let earth = new Planet(23, 'wooow');
```

Question: How can I condition the creation of the instance so that if parameter types are respected --> instance created, otherwise don't assign anything to `earth`

EDIT: I forgot to specify that I am expecting a `Planet(String, boolean)` parameters type

Comment: JS in-built thing for such validations is Proxy object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: You can throw an exception! It is not possible to return undefined from a constructor function. You would have to wrap it then in another creator function that returns a new Planet or undefined/null depending on the parameters.

Comment: @wostex No, proxies help absolutely nothing here

Comment: How am I supposed to know what parameter types to respect?

Comment: How should I specify them if there are no explicit types? I was thinking though about using typeof()

Comment: If you want type checking, then use a language such as TypeScript which provides it. In your example, how are you going to continue running your program if `earth` is not set to anything?

Comment: @Bergi why? You can use a Proxy to intercept constructors. Look at my answer.

Comment: @wostex Ah, to "*intercept an existing constructor*", yes why not (though usually you'd completely overwrite it with a decorated one). But assuming that you just can edit the constructor code, there's much easier and better solutions.

Comment: @Bergi it's true :)

Answer (score 1):

There are some solutions to do it:

- return an object without any property

```js
    function Planet(solarSystem,habitable) {
        if (typeof solarSystem != 'string' && typeof habitable != 'boolean') {
           return Object.create(null);
        }
        this.solarSystem = solarSystem;
        this.habitable = habitable;
    }
    
    var planetObj1 = new Planet('TEST', true);
    console.log('planetObj1 ' , planetObj1 , 'is instanceof Planet', planetObj1 instanceof Planet);
    var planetObj2 = new Planet(14, 'TEST');
    console.log('planetObj2 ', planetObj2, 'is instanceof Planet', planetObj2  instanceof Planet);
```

- if you want to return any others JavaScript type such as undefined, null. You can create a prototype to handle it

You can create a prototype to decide to create your new Obj or not

```js
function Planet(solarSystem,habitable) {

        this.solarSystem = solarSystem;
        this.habitable = habitable;

    }

    Planet.CreatePlanet = function(solarSystem, habitable) { 
        if (typeof solarSystem != 'string' && typeof habitable != 'boolean') return null;
        return new Planet(solarSystem, habitable);
    }

    // then instead of new Planet():
    var obj = Planet.CreatePlanet(14, 'habitable');//return null
    console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Proxy` object to intercept an existing constructor and apply your validation logic:

```js
function Planet(solarSystem,habitable) {
    this.solarSystem = solarSystem;
    this.habitable = habitable;
}

const validate = { // handler for Proxy
  construct: function(target, args) {
    let solarSystem, habitable;
    if (Array.isArray(args) && args.length === 2) {
      solarSystem = (typeof args[0] === 'string') ? args[0] : null;
      habitable = (typeof args[1] === 'boolean') ? args[1] : null;
      return ( solarSystem !== null && habitable !== null)
       ? { solarSystem, habitable} 
        : {}
    } else {
     return {} // return an empty object in case of bad arguments
    }
  }
}

// new constructor, use it to create new planets
const validPlanet = new Proxy(Planet, validate); 
// usage: const a = new validPlanet(<string>, <boolean>)

// let's use initial buggy constructor:

const earth = new Planet('solar', true);
console.log('earth (Planet): ', earth);

const wrong = new Planet('solar', 15); // this uses the initial constructor, wrong value passes
console.log('wrong (Planet): ', wrong);

// now let's use proxied constrictor with validation

const pluto = new validPlanet('solar', false);
console.log('pluto (validPlanet): ', pluto);

const bad = new validPlanet('solar', 'hello');
console.log('bad (validPlanet): ', bad); // returns an empty object
```

It's impossible to return 'undefined' here if you provide wrong inputs, because `Proxy.construct` **must** return an object. If an empty object is ok, then this should work for you.